# Webpack build error - Unexpected token: name (OrbitControls)

Tags: webpack, three.js, bundle, source-maps, uglifyjs

I have the following error when building webpack for production using the *‘source-map’* devtool:

```
ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (OrbitControls) [./node_modules/orbit-controls-es6/src/index.js:33,0][bundle.js:57444,6]
```

The build has been working fine for development using the *'cheap-module-eval-source-map'* webpack devtool.

The module that Uglify seems to take issue with is the [orbit-controls-es6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/orbit-controls-es6) module used for Three.js camera control, pointing to the main class declaration:

```
export default class OrbitControls extends EventDispatcher {…
```

Can someone explain to me why this might be occurring? I’m not sure if it’s an issue with the module or with my own code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you happen to have a circular dependency?

also I use this version from npm and works fine with webpack

https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-orbitcontrols

import OrbitControls from 'three-orbitcontrols'

Comment: Replacing the OrbitControls module with the one you linked resolved the issue. Thank you!